# Negative Level of Significance?

Tags: r, statistical-significance

I have been trying to construct a Correlogram in R for which I have installed the `corrplot` package. I have been trying to combine the correlations along with the significance test so that I can visualize which of the correlations are insignificant. I have taken the `mtcars` dataset and have typed the following commands:

```
> library(corrplot)
> M=cor(mtcars)
> corrplot(M,method="circle")
> cor.mtest=function(mat,conf.level=0.95){
+ mat=as.matrix(mat)
+ n=ncol(mat)
+ p.mat=lowCI.mat=uppCI.mat=matrix(NA,n,n)
+ diag(p.mat)=0
+ diag(lowCI.mat)=diag(uppCI.mat)=1
+ for(i in 1:(n-1)){
+ for(j in (i+1):n){
+ tmp=cor.test(mat[,i],mat[,j],conf.level=conf.level)
+ p.mat[i,j]=p.mat[j,i]=tmp$p.value
+ lowCI.mat[i,j]=lowCI.mat[j,i]=tmp$conf.int[1]
+ uppCI.mat[i,j]=uppCI.mat[j,i]=tmp$conf.int[2]
+ }
+ }
+ return(list(p.mat,lowCI.mat,uppCI.mat))
+ }
> res1=cor.mtest(mtcars,0.95)
> res2=cor.mtest(mtcars,0.99)
> corrplot(M,p.mat=res1[[1]],sig.level = 0.05)
```

Also,again when I typed the same line of code but with a negative significance level i.e
`corrplot(M,p.mat=res1[[1]],sig.level = -0.05)`,
R provides the plot. I want to know what does negative level of significance implies?

Comment: From the corrplot documentation:  "if the p-value in p-mat is bigger than sig.level, then the corresponding correlation coefficient is regarded as insignificant."  Since p-values are never negative, inputting a negative value here should automatically regard all correlations as non-significant.

Comment: Several interpretations are possible. One is that you found a small bug in the software, namely that this is allowed. A more optimistic interpretation is that users are expected to know what makes sense for their situation.

Answer (score 0):

Answered in comments:

> From the corrplot documentation: "if the p-value in p-mat is bigger
> than sig.level, then the corresponding correlation coefficient is
> regarded as insignificant." Since p-values are never negative,
> inputting a negative value here should automatically regard all
> correlations as non-significant.

– Jacob Socolar

> Several interpretations are possible. One is that you found a small
> bug in the software, namely that this is allowed. A more optimistic
> interpretation is that users are expected to know what makes sense for
> their situation.

– Nick Cox